# Switching Evernote key from Sandbox to Production Process (IOS)

Tags: ios, evernote

I requested an Evernote API key and have been using it in the sandbox environment without issue. I requested to activate it on Production using the request form and I received an email saying it has been updated. What else do I need to do to move my app from the sandbox to production environment? When I run my IOS app it is still running in the Sandbox environment. There aren't instructions in the email or anywhere else I can find.

Answer (score 1):

Doh, **in the authenticate call** you have to change the optionHost to `nil` instead of `ENSessionHostSandbox`. I was thinking they would automatically figure out which environment to used based on the key.

```
ENSession.setSharedSessionConsumerKey("xxxx", consumerSecret:"xxxxx", optionalHost: nil)
```